# document.write() overrides the current HTML conent. How to get around this?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an existing HTML file as follows-

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/ html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet"   type="text/css" href="chatWindow.css" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Chat Window</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <table>
   <tr> <textarea id="chatTextArea"  rows="20" cols = "80"></textarea> </tr>
   <tr> <textarea id="messageTextArea" rows="5"  cols="80"></textarea> </tr>
 </table>
 <script type="text/javascript" src ="jquery-1.7.1.js" ></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="liveChat.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I open this HTML in a new window from JavaScript code as follows -

```
 var chatWindow = window.open("chatWindow.html", "Chat Window", "resizable=0,width=700,height=600");
```

Now, to this existing window, I want to add another field. I tried -

```
 var chatWindow = window.open("chatWindow.html", "Chat Window", "resizable=0,width=700,height=600");
 chatWindow.document.write(' Hey!!  <input type="hidden" id="currentUserName" value="' + userName+ '"  / >  ');
```

But this overrode the existing HTML and so all I saw on my page was "Hey!!".

I also tried

```
  var chatWindow = window.open("chatWindow.html", "Chat Window", "resizable=0,width=700,height=600");
  var hiddenNode = chatWindow.document.createElement('input');
  hiddenNode.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
  hiddenNode.setAttribute("id", "currentUserName");
  hiddenNode.setAttribute("value", userName);

  chatWindow.document.body.appendChild(hiddenNode);
```

But this had no affect. When the new window opened, I checked its page source and the hidden node was not found. How to solve this problem? Please help.

Comment: Try using `.appendChild` in a load handler, e.g. `chatWindow.onload = function() { ... }`.

Comment: Did you check what the console says? Are there any errors?

Comment: @pimvdb  Tried it. Didn't work.

Comment: @hotS85 Console doesn't give any errors. I checked it.

Comment: When you say you checked the 'source,' did you check the HTML source ('view source') or the DOM (with Firebug, Web Inspector, Dragonfly..)? JavaScript doesn't change the HTML of the page, just the DOM. So the hidden node might be there, if you 'inspect element' in Firebug, Web Inspector (or whichever other tool).

Answer (score 0):

You should use appendChild.

```
chatWindow.document.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hey !"));
```

You may also use jQuery to do this more easily.

Comment: And with a div in your chatWindow ? 
var mydiv = chatWindow.document.getElementById("mydiv");
mydiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("bar"));

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign properties instead of attributes.

```
chatWindow = window.open("chatWindow.html"...);

hiddenNode=chatWindow.document.body.appendChild(chatWindow.document.createElement('INPUT'));
hiddenNode.type='hidden';
hiddenNode.id='currentUserName';
hiddenNode.value=userName;
```

**Edited**:

If the browser opens the window in a new tab, it is accessible as well through `chatWindow`.
(Succesfully tested with Chrome, FF and IE.)

Comment: @CodeBlue I've edited my answer. I was wrong about new tabs. The code is tested and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try `chatWindow.document.body.appendChild(/* [...] */);`.